# How to install latest intervention/image in laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I want to upgrade my project and checking https://image.intervention.io/v3/ package I see that 2x version is absolute.

But I failed to remove this project with message :

```
$ composer why intervention/image
league/glide 2.3.0 requires intervention/image (^2.7)
```

I tried manually to add line :

```
"intervention/image": "^3.4.0",
```

But next errors :

```
$ composer install
No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - league/glide[1.4.0, ..., 1.x-dev, 2.0.0] require intervention/image ^2.4 -> found intervention/image[2.4.0, ..., 2.7.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.4.0).
    - league/glide 2.0.x-dev requires intervention/image ^2.1 -> found intervention/image[2.1.0, ..., 2.7.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.4.0).
    - league/glide[2.1.0, ..., 2.3.0] require intervention/image ^2.7 -> found intervention/image[2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.4.0).
    - spatie/image[1.5.3, ..., 1.7.6] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - spatie/browsershot[3.61.0, ..., v3.x-dev] require spatie/image ^1.5.3|^2.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/image[1.5.3, ..., v1.x-dev, 2.0.0, ..., v2.x-dev].
    - spatie/image[1.10.0, ..., v1.x-dev] require league/glide ^1.6 -> satisfiable by league/glide[1.6.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - spatie/image[1.7.7, ..., 1.9.0] require league/glide ^1.4 -> satisfiable by league/glide[1.4.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - spatie/image[1.11.0, 2.2.2, ..., v2.x-dev] require league/glide ^2.2.2 -> satisfiable by league/glide[2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.3.0].
    - spatie/image[1.10.3, 2.0.0, ..., 2.2.1] require league/glide ^2.0 -> satisfiable by league/glide[2.0.0, ..., 2.3.0].
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/browsershot ^3.61 -> satisfiable by spatie/browsershot[3.61.0, v3.x-dev].
```

My composer.json has :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "adldap2/adldap2-laravel": "^6.1.7",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^6.6.4",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^10.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^v10.44.0",
        "laravel/pennant": "^1.6",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.24.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.53",
        "mailchimp/marketing": "^3.0.80",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.4.1",
        "mongodb/laravel-mongodb": "^4.1.1",
        "opcodesio/log-viewer": "^1.9.1",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "^1.2",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^2.0",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^3.8.2",
        "snipe/banbuilder": "dev-master",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.61"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.10.5",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.15.1",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23.0",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.28.2",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.13.11",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.27.4",
        "laravel/telescope": "*",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6.7",
        "intervention/image": "^3.4.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.4.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.6.16",
        "sempro/phpunit-pretty-print": "^1.4",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.4.2",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],

        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/telescope"
            ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

It does not have any league/glide package and I how to install latest verion of image.intervention ?

Comment: Change version of `spatie/browsershot` (upgrade to v4? Downgrate even more?) as it's main pacage that requires deeper requirements that stops composer execution